# Why is my token rotation not working in nextAuth

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, jwt, next-auth

I am building a web application with an external API that my self and my team member are working on. We simply make API requests from nextjs. I implemented nextauth for authentication but the token rotation does not work.
On a successful login, user makes an API request to our backend and gets Access Token and Refresh token. The Access Token lasts for 10 minutes while the refresh token lasts longer. I saved the Access token in nextAuth session and can access it across the app. When user make an API request, I attached the access token to it enable the user make an API request. I am using Axios for making the requests.
When an access Token expires, I used axios interceptor to request for a new access token as long as the refresh token is valid.
So far, it works and the refresh token gets to be called which generates new access token and new refresh token. Unfortunately, nextAuth still goes on to attach the old and expired access token to the api request and the request fails.
What Am I doing wrongly here? It is my first time of using nextjs.
We are considering quitting nextAuth and simply do it our way.
Get the access token and refresh token, save refresh token in redis, pass refreshtoken as http only cookie. Save the user's sessionId in local storage for persistent login and save access token in-memory and attach it on every API call.
However, we dont know if this approach is solid enough or we should try and make nextAuth to work. Kindly assist me, please.

Here are some of my codes:

```
`  const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
     session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },

  providers:[
    CredentialsProvider({
        type: "credentials",
        credentials: {},

       async authorize(credentials, req){
            const { username, password } = credentials as {
                username: string;
                password: string;
              };

              if(!credentials){
                return null
              }
              const userData = {
                username: username,
                password: password
              }
            

              try {
                
                const response = await axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/login`, userData);
                if(response?.data){
                  
                  const user: jwtDecodedAttributes = jwt_decode(response?.data?.userToken);
                  
                  return {
                    id: user.userId,
                    name: user.username,
                    role: user.role,
                    profilepicture: user.profilepicture,
                    iat: user?.iat,
                    exp: user?.exp,
                    username: user?.username,
                    token: response?.data?.userToken,
                    email: user.email,
                    userId: user?.userId,
                    refresh: response?.data.userRefreshToken
                  };
            }
             
                
              } catch (error) {
                
                
              }
              return null
        }
    })
  ],

  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
  },

callbacks:{
 async jwt({token, user, trigger, session}){
  if (trigger === "update") {
    return { ...token, ...session.user };
  }

      return {...token, ...user} ;
  },

 async session({session, token, user}){
    
    session.user = token
   
    
    return session
 }
}
};


 export default NextAuth(authOptions);

 `
```

The refresh token function

```
export const RefreshFunction = ()=>{
         const { status, data, update } = useSession();



    const refreshToken = async()=>{
  const getItem = localStorage.getItem('refresh');
  const refreshData = {
    refresh: getItem,
   
  }
   
   if(data?.user.refresh){
    try {
      const res = await axios.post<axiosGetRefreshTokenAttributes>(`${BASE_URL}/refresh`, refreshData);

      const accessToken = res?.data?.userToken
      const refreshToken = res?.data?.refreshToken
      localStorage.removeItem('refresh');
     
      if(data?.user){
        await update({
          ...data,
          user:{
            ...data?.user,
            token: accessToken,
            refresh: refreshToken

          }
          
        })
       
       
        
      }
      localStorage.setItem('refresh', refreshToken as string)
     
    } catch (error) {
      return error
    }
   }

  }

   return refreshToken
   };
```

Axios interceptor function:

```
const useAxiosPrivate = () =>{
   const { status, data } = useSession();
   const refreshToken = RefreshFunction()



useEffect(() =>{
    const requestInterceptors = axiosPrivate.interceptors.request.use(
        config =>{
            if(!config.headers['authorization']){
                config.headers['authorization'] = `Bearer ${data?.user?.token}`
            }
            return config;
        }, (error) => Promise.reject(error)
    );

    const responseIntercept = axiosPrivate.interceptors.response.use(
        response => response,
        async (error)=>{
            const prevRequest = error?.config;
            console.log(error.response.status, 'kkk')
            if(error?.response.status === 401 && !prevRequest?.sent){
                prevRequest.sent = true;
               
                const token = await refreshToken()
                 prevRequest.headers['authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
                
                 return axiosPrivate(prevRequest);
                
               
            }
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }
    );

    return()=>{
        axiosPrivate.interceptors.request.eject(requestInterceptors)
        axiosPrivate.interceptors.response.eject(responseIntercept)
    }

}, [data?.user?.token])

return axiosPrivate;
};


export default useAxiosPrivate;`
```

An example of an API call:

```
const { status, data } = useSession();

 await axiosPrivate.post(`/createcompany`, companyData,  
 {withCredentials: true, headers: {Authorization: ` 
 ${data?.user.token}`}});
```

Like I said, the refresh endpoints get to be called when it detects that the access token has expired and it generates new access token and refresh token. Unfortunately, the new access token doesn't get attached to the nextAuth session.
The error message is that my access token has expired. This means that the newly generated access token dont get attached.

Answer (score 1):

Next-Auth is just a hobby app I am afraid, it is no where ready for use in production. The fact that you have to code the refresh token logic yourself is a huge give away for this.

Next Auth's very scant documentation on how to do this is here:
https://next-auth.js.org/v3/tutorials/refresh-token-rotation

Looks like you need to implement a date check, if the access token has expired then refresh it. I warn you this looks simple but it is not. You are bound to encounter x amount of new and interesting bugs when you try to implement this in both dev and production environments.

```
    async function refreshAccessToken(token) {
  try {
    const url =
      "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token?" +
      new URLSearchParams({
        client_id: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        grant_type: "refresh_token",
        refresh_token: token.refreshToken,
      })

    const response = await fetch(url, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      },
      method: "POST",
    })

    const refreshedTokens = await response.json()

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw refreshedTokens
    }

    return {
      ...token,
      accessToken: refreshedTokens.access_token,
      accessTokenExpires: Date.now() + refreshedTokens.expires_in * 1000,
      refreshToken: refreshedTokens.refresh_token ?? token.refreshToken, // Fall back to old refresh token
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)

    return {
      ...token,
      error: "RefreshAccessTokenError",
    }
  }
}
```

And in the callbacks...

```
async jwt(token, user, account) {
  // Initial sign in
  if (account && user) {
    return {
      accessToken: account.accessToken,
      accessTokenExpires: Date.now() + account.expires_in * 1000,
      refreshToken: account.refresh_token,
      user,
    }
  }

  // Return previous token if the access token has not expired yet
  if (Date.now() < token.accessTokenExpires) {
    return token
  }

  // Access token has expired, try to update it
  return refreshAccessToken(token)
},
```

My advice is to just only use the Next Auth frame work with what it has available "out of the box" (and refresh tokens are not available out of the box) as soon as you try to make a framework do things it hasn't been designed for you are entering coding hell my friend.

Comment: Thanks man, I have abandoned it honestly and moved to implementing the system my self. Lot more easier for me that way.

Comment: Some useful youtube videos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xMsJPnjiRAc&t=434s  ,  https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLJRGQoqpRwddLqVtViDg4IILOTry1VjjP , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nI8PYZNFtac&t=366s , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IUbNmsk9diY